# How can I use the Radon-Nikodym theorem to show that forward measure is indeed measure?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, risk-neutral-measure, forward, numerairechange

The following statements are taken from [the Wikipedia page for forward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_measure#Mathematical_definition).

> Let
>   $$B(T)=\exp \left(\int _{0}^{T}r(u)\,du\right)$$
>   be the bank account or money market account numeraire and
>   $$D(T)=1/B(T)=\exp \left(-\int _{0}^{T}r(u)\,du\right)$$
>   be the discount factor in the market at time 0 for maturity T.
>   If $Q_{*}$ is the risk neutral measure, then the forward measure $Q_{T}$ is defined via the **Radon–Nikodym derivative** given by
>   $$\frac{dQ_{T}}{dQ_{*}}={\frac {1}{B(T)E_{Q_{*}}[1/B(T)]}}={\frac {D(T)}{E_{Q_{*}}[D(T)]}}.$$

How can I use the [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) to prove that $Q_T$ defined above is indeed a measure?

Comment: What is your question exactly: to verify that $Q_T$ has the properties of of a probability measure (i.e. function image in $[0,1]$, and countable additivity of disjoint sets)?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Just to briefly add to Daneel's top answer, start with $$Q_T[A]:=E_{Q_*}\left[1_A \frac{D(T)}{E_{Q_*}[D(T)]}\right].$$

1. Since $D(T)>0$, we have that $Q_T$ is always non-negative. As usual, $Q_T[\emptyset]=0$ and $Q_T[\Omega]=1$.
2. Let $A_1,A_2,...$ be a sequence of disjoint sets taken from $\mathcal{F}$. Then,
   \begin{align*}
   Q_T\left[\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right] &= E_{Q_*}\left[1_{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k}\frac{D(T)}{E_{Q_*}[D(T)]}\right] \\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty E_{Q_*}\left[1_{A_k}\frac{D(T)}{E_{Q_*}[D(T)]}\right] \\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty Q_T\left[1_{A_k}\right],
   \end{align*}
   where the second equality stems from splitting up the integral domain.

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction**

Technically, I don't think you need the Radon-Nikodym theorem here. That theorem assumes the existence of two equivalent probability measures $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ and states that there must exist a random variable $\xi$ such that $Q_2$ is defined as the expectation of $\xi$ under $Q_1$. What you need here is more akin to Theorem 1.6.1 in Shreve (2004), namely given a measure $Q_1$ and a random variables $\xi$, prove that you can construct a well-defined probability measure $Q_2$.

---

**Radon-Nikodym Derivative**

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},Q_*)$ be a probability space equipped with the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq 0}$, where $Q_*$ is the risk-neutral measure. $B(t)$ is defined as the money market account, and $P(t,T)$ as the zero-coupon bond with maturity $0\leq t\leq T$. We have:
$$P(0,T)=E^{Q_*}\left(\left.\frac{B(0)}{B(T)}\right.\right)$$
By definition, $B(t)>0$, which implies $P(t,T)>0$. Let us define the random-variable $\xi$:
$$\xi:=\frac{B(0)P(T,T)}{B(T)P(0,T)}$$
By the preceding, the random variable $\xi$ is strictly positive. Additionally, under the risk-neutral measure $Q_*$, $\xi$ has expectation $1$ by the martingale property of discounted payoffs:
$$E^{Q_*}\left(\xi\right)=\frac{B(0)}{P(0,T)}E^{Q_*}\left(\frac{P(T,T)}{B(T)}\right)=1$$
Hence $\xi$ is a valid Radon-Nikodym derivative and we can define the $T$-forward measure $Q_T$ as follows, for any $F\in\mathcal{F}$:
$$Q_T(F):=E^{Q_*}\left(\xi 1_{F}\right)=\int_{\omega\in F}\xi(\omega) dQ_*(\omega)$$

**1) Image in $[0,1]$**: note that, for any $F\in\mathcal{F}$:
$$0 \leq 1_F \leq 1_\Omega$$
Thus:
$$0\leq E^{Q_*}\left(\xi 1_F\right)\leq E^{Q_*}\left(\xi 1_\Omega\right)=\int_{\omega\in \Omega}\xi(\omega) dQ_*(\omega)=E^{Q_*}\left(\xi\right)=1$$

**2) Countable additivity of disjoint sets**: note that, for any $F_1,F_2\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $F_1\cap F_2=\emptyset$:
$$1_{F_1\cup F_2}=1_{F_1}+1_{F_2}-1_{F_1\cap F_2} = 1_{F_1}+1_{F_2}$$
which generalizes. Thus for an infinite, countable sequence of events $F_1, F_2, \dots$, you can use the fact that $0\leq 1_{\cup_{n>0} F_n}<2$ to invoke the dominated convergence theorem and conclude that:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n>0}Q_T(F_n)
=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i\leq n}\int_\Omega\xi(\omega)1_{F_i}(\omega)dQ_*(\omega)
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_\Omega\xi(\omega)1_{\cup_{i\leq n}F_i}(\omega)dQ_*(\omega)
\\
&=\int_\Omega\xi(\omega)1_{\cup_{n>0} F_n}(\omega)dQ_*(\omega)
\\[8pt]
&=Q_T(\cup_{n>0} F_n)
\end{align}$$

---

**Radon-Nikodym Derivative Process**

You can extend the Radon-Nikodym derivative to any time $t\in(0,T]$ by constructing the Radon-Nikodym derivative process. This is done via the conditional expectation:
$$\xi(t):=E^{Q_*}\left(\xi|\mathcal{F}_t\right)=E^{Q_*}\left(\left.\frac{B(0)P(T,T)}{B(T)P(0,T)}\right|\mathcal{F}_t\right)=\frac{B(0)P(t,T)}{B(t)P(0,T)},$$
where we have used the fact that any traded-asset rebased by the money market account is a martingale under $Q_*$. You can easily verify the properties proved for $t=0$ are carried over.

---

**References**

Steven Shreve. *Stochastic Calculus in Finance II: Continuous Time Models*. Springer, 2004.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I feel like this way overcomplicates the answer. If you have a measure $\mu$ on some measurable space $\Omega$ and a non-negative measurable function $f,$ then $\nu(A) = \int_A f$ will define always measure. In this case, it's also obvious, that $\int_\Omega f = 1,$  so it's a probability measure.

Comment: @LazyCat what you say is correct, but it is not straightforward: it is actually a theorem. What I am doing is displaying some steps on how the underlying argument goes. I am also showing why the ratio of numéraires is a well-defined Radon-Nikodym derivative. I am also making clear the construction of the RN derivative _along t_.

Comment: In particular, the OP asked about how to verify $Q_T$ is a well-defined probability measure using the RN theorem, but the RN theorem is unapplicable in that context.

Comment: which part in my comment is not obvious? I feel like it's a trivial and very generic observation.

Comment: Well, OP asks the question so he obviously does not find it trivial or wants further details; and there are theorems out there, such as Radon-Nikodym, carefully establishing these results and under what conditions they hold.

Comment: @LazyCat your obvious observation is actually missing a critical assumption: why is it obvious that $\int_\Omega fd\mu=1$?

Comment: Well, my point is that unless I am mistaken your response is much more complicated than needs be. For your second question - this is precisely how the denominator is in OP's formula is chosen - to normalize the whole thing to 1.

Comment: This discussion is extending unnecessarily and I am not sure what the endpoint is. Yes, the denominator is chosen so that the RN derivative’s expectation is 1: is the OP aware that this is a condition for the RN derivative to be well-defined? I don’t know, I gave an answer quite detailed so that the construction of new measures with other numéraires is sufficiently clear. Please feel free to give an alternative answer. The more derivations posted, the richer the resources of this site will be.

Comment: @LazyCat regarding your comment, then it’s misleading: that is generally not true, it is true for $f$ constructed as a ratio of numéraires. And it is true because of the martingale property under the risk-neutral measure.

Comment: what is not true? That $\nu(A) = \frac1Z \int_A f,$ where $Z = \int_\Omega f$ is a probability measure?

Comment: I appreciate that you try to make the discussion constructive, but the integral of Gaussian density over R is definitely one, not zero.

Comment: Terrible mistake, I was thinking about the expectation. But you can simply take $f(x)=|x|$. Don't you see your first comment is wrong? Unless I am totally misinterpreting your notation, what you are saying is: "the expectation of any non-negative measurable function $f$ under a probability measure is *always* equal to $1$" (that is literally what is written in your comment). If you are changing measures, be specific, otherwise it's ambiguous. In fact, you've amended yourself. Which one is it, $\nu(A)=1/Z\int_A f$ or $\nu(A)=\int_A f$? Which measures? etc.

Comment: And anyway, I really don't see what your point is: why don't you simply put this into an answer?

Comment: I certainly didn't mean it to become a pissing contest. I was surprised by your rather involved answer to what seemed to be such a simple question, and assumed I am missing something obvious. Doesn't seem to be the case so far. Yes, you are reading misreading my comments. In the first comment, I meant the function $f$ in the OP's question which is already normalized, in the later one I meant a general function, which still needs to be normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment thread to Daneel's answer became even longer than his original answer, I thought of putting my comments here separately.

I believe, that wiki quotation refers is the following simple fact:

If you have an integrable measurable non-negative $f$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mu),$ the $\nu(A) = \int_A f d\mu$ always defines a measure on $\Omega.$ In particular, there's no need to check things like countable additivity, it simply follows from the corresponding properties of the integral.

In general, if $\int_\Omega f d\mu > 0,$ one can normalize this measure be a probability measure: $\nu(A) = \frac1Z \int_A f d\mu,$ where $Z = \int_\Omega f d\mu$

In this case $f$ referred as a Radon-Nikodym derivative is already normalized, so you get a probability measure.